# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Tags: python, tkinter

I know this has been asked, but I cannot get a solution to this problem. I am attempting to use tkinter on Windows 11. I read it is supposed to come with newer versions of Python. When I run the following code, I get the ModuleNotFoundError.

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
```

I checked my Python version:

`python --version Python 3.11.1`

I also noticed some people online were attempting to install with python3. It seems I do not have python3 as a command. Is this the root of my issue?

Comment: What is the platform? How do you install Python?

Comment: Sorry, I am on Windows. Python came installed on my machine